# Tomcat7/Java Project: Finding out the starting point, where does my application starts?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, maven

I have to analyze a Spring/Maven/Java with Hibernate Application. What I do, I start from the entry point of the application, where I can log in (it is a JSP based web app). 
But is this really the point where the application starts and does its initialisation? 
I do not find a main function, so my question is, and believe me I have searched for it quiet a long time, 
how can I find the starting point? 
The class, the method, which is started at first, for example when tomcat starts?

Comment: a web application does not have an entry point, however it has a welcome page list, e.g. <welcome-file-list><welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file</welcome-file-list> in web.xml of your webapp. If you start the webapp  on your local machine, you would be able to access this welcome page by typing in the browser url box something like http://localhost:8080/<your-app-name>. Then you click on different links and observe how do they map to the different java classes of your application - but this is framework specific.

Comment: Thanks, so I found my entry point! I already had it, I just thought, there is some preceding steps! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by John Donn above!